# Fit function with preallocated buffer memory in scipy.optimize.leastsq

Tags: python, memory-management, numpy, scipy, data-fitting

I am trying to use `scipy.optimize.leastsq` with a fit function that uses preallocated memory to store the residuals. I have millions of nonlinear fits and time is critical. I had the fit function coded in `C`, and I noticed that `scipy.optimize.leastsq` didn't work correctly when the fit function simply returned a reference to the buffer memory that was obtained as an input. I thought I had screwed up with the `Py_INCREF`s when I noticed that the problem can be reproduced in pure `Python`. Here is some mock-up code that illustrates the issue (the actual problem has different fit functions and is much more complicated):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

# the mock-up data to be fitted
x = np.arange(5.)
noise = np.array([0.0, -0.02, 0.01, -0.03, 0.01])
y = np.exp(-x) + noise

# preallocate the buffer memory
buf = np.empty_like(x)

# fit function writing residuals to preallocated memory and returning a reference 
def dy(p, x, buf, y):
    buf[:] = p[0]*np.exp(-p[1]*x) - y
    return buf

# starting values (true values are [1., 1.])
p0 = np.array([1.2, 0.8])

# leastsq with dy(): DOESN'T WORK CORRECTLY
opt.leastsq(dy, p0, args=(x, buf, y))
# -> (array([ 1.2,  0.8]), 4)
```

To make it work correctly, I have to wrap the fit function into one that makes a copy:

```
# wrapper that calls dy() and returns a copy of the array
def dy2(*args): 
    return dy(*args).copy()

# leastsq with dy2(): WORKS CORRECTLY
opt.leastsq(dy2, p0, args=(x, buf, y))
# -> (array([ 0.99917134,  1.03603201]), 1)
```

...but making a copy obviously defeats using buffer memory in the first place! As a side note, `opt.fmin` also works with the buffer memory like so (but is in practice much too slow for my application):

```
def sum2(p, x, buf, y):
    dy(p, x, buf, y)
    return buf.dot(buf)

opt.fmin(sum2, p0, args=(x, buf, y))
# Optimization terminated successfully.
#     Current function value: 0.001200
#     Iterations: 32
#     Function evaluations: 63
# -> array([ 0.99915812,  1.03600273])
```

Any ideas why `scipy.optimize.leastsq` works correctly with `dy2()` and not with `dy()` in the above example?

Comment: Are you sure that internally a buffer is not reused? from `leastsq` code the minpack functions `_minpack._lmdif` and `_minpack._lmder` are called and no calculations besides argument checking are done before that. I would assume that they do that internally. So there is no need for you to preallocate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think this is what happens here: The underlying `FORTRAN` routine `LMDIF` presents the user-defined function with memory in `*fvec`, where the result is to be stored. This pointer may point to scratch memory, since `LMDIF` needs to cache the results of several function evaluations to estimate the Jacobian.

Since the user-defined function is called from `Python`, the memory in `*fvec` cannot be used directly, so the wrapper `raw_multipack_lm_function()` works by evaluating the `Python` function first and *then* coping the result to `*fvec`. Before entering `LMDIF`, the user-defined function is called once to find out the shape of the output array.

The problem arises because the memory from the first function evaluation is then passed to `LMDIF` as the original `*fvec`, as if it was new disposable memory. `LMDIF` goes on to use it to store the first function evaluation in and then calls the user function again with a different `*fvec`. But in the example with `dy()`, the user function overwrites the memory from the previous function call before the result is copied to the memory where `LMDIF` wants it. This fools `LMDIF` into thinking that the result never changes, hence exiting with the case that the fit parameters have no impact on the quality of the fit.

I consider this a bug in `minpack_lmdif()` from `scipy/optimize/__minpack.h`, since it assumes that the user-defined function always returns new disposable memory, which is not the case with `dy()` (which seems to be a perfectly legitimate way to code the fit function).  The following `git diff` illustrates an easy fix:

```
diff --git a/scipy/optimize/__minpack.h b/scipy/optimize/__minpack.h
index 2c0ea33..465724b 100644
--- a/scipy/optimize/__minpack.h
+++ b/scipy/optimize/__minpack.h
@@ -483,7 +483,7 @@ static PyObject *minpack_lmdif(PyObject *dummy, PyObject *args) {
   qtf = (double *) ap_qtf->data;
   fjac = (double *) ap_fjac->data;
   ldfjac = dims[1];
-  wa = (double *)malloc((3*n + m)* sizeof(double));
+  wa = (double *)malloc((3*n + 2*m)* sizeof(double));
   if (wa == NULL) {
     PyErr_NoMemory();
     goto fail;
@@ -492,12 +492,15 @@ static PyObject *minpack_lmdif(PyObject *dummy, PyObject *args) {

   /* Call the underlying FORTRAN routines. */
   n_int = n; /* to provide int*-pointed storage for int argument of LMDIF */
-  LMDIF(raw_multipack_lm_function, &m, &n_int, x, fvec, &ftol, &xtol, &gtol, &maxfev, &epsfcn, diag,
-    
+  LMDIF(raw_multipack_lm_function, &m, &n_int, x, wa+3*n+m, &ftol, &xtol, &gtol, &maxfev, &epsfcn, d
+
   RESTORE_FUNC();

   if (info < 0) goto fail;           /* Python error */

+  /* Copy final residuals back to initial array */
+  memcpy(fvec, wa+3*n+m, m*sizeof(double));
+
   free(wa);
   Py_DECREF(extra_args); 
   Py_DECREF(ap_diag);
```

So we allocate `m` more elements of scratch space for `LMDIF` and use the additional memory as the initial `*fvec`. This prevents the memory collision when the user function is called. To return the correct final residual, an additional `memcpy()` is needed to store the final result in the original array.

As in the original example with dy(), this allows one to code the fit function to be free from memory allocations. Since the whole inner loop in `LMDIF` is then free of memory allocations, an improved performance can be expected.

**Update**

Here are some timing results. Obviously, the test problem is very small and fast converging, so it might not be representative for real-world applications. This is with the patched version of `scipy.optimize.leastsq`:

```
In [1]: def dy0(p, x, y): return p[0]*np.exp(-p[1]*x) - y

In [2]: %timeit p = opt.leastsq(dy2, p0, args=(x, buf, y))
1000 loops, best of 3: 399 us per loop

In [3]: %timeit p = opt.leastsq(dy, p0, args=(x, buf, y))
1000 loops, best of 3: 363 us per loop

In [4]: %timeit p = opt.leastsq(dy0, p0, args=(x, y))
1000 loops, best of 3: 341 us per loop
```

So nothing can be gained by writing to preallocated memory: The straightforward implementation of `dy0()` is the fastest. But what if we write a more efficient wrapper for `LMDIF` that takes better advantage of the preallocated memory? Here is one I wrote:

```
In [5]: %timeit p = mp.leastsq(dy, (p0.copy(), x, buf, y))
1000 loops, best of 3: 279 us per loop
```

That's something. `mp.leastsq` still evaluates a general `Python` function, with the restriction that the 1st argument will be overwritten with the result and the 3rd argument is the buffer memory. But let's see what happens if we code `dy()` in `C`:

```
In [6]: %timeit p = opt.leastsq(fitfun.e2_diff, p0, args=(x, buf, y))
10000 loops, best of 3: 48.2 us per loop
```

Ouch! So much for `numpy`'s performance of perfectly vectorized code (at least for short arrays). Let's use the improved wrapper:

```
In [7]: %timeit p = mp.leastsq(fitfun.e2_diff, (p0.copy(), x, buf, y))
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.94 us per loop
```

The additional acceleration between `opt.leastsq` and `mp.leastsq` comes from getting rid of tuple-building code and `memcpy`s. Finally, the raw performance of `LMDIF` without calling back into `Python`:

```
In [8]: %timeit p = fitfun.e2_fit(p0.copy(), x, buf, y)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.13 us per loop
```

Not much different. So calling back into Python doesn't appear to cost much, but don't let `numpy` do the computation for you! Further speedups for many subsequent fits (my application) can come from reusing the scratch memory `wa` for `LMDIF`.

Most importantly, all computations return the correct result now!

Comment: so, what is the speed up for you?

Comment: @Bort: I added some timing results. There is no speedup for the Python implementation that reuses the buffer memory, but it gives me the possibility to test with functions that behave the same way as a C implementation later on, with huge performance benefits.